# Using context to share a common timeout across consecutive function calls

Tags: go, go-context

I want to make some consecutive function calls in a Go program, e.g.

(error checking apparently ommitted)

```
result1, err := fxn1()

result2, err := fxn2()
```

I want the entire call sequence to be completed within a certain duration, otherwise the process should be aborted (and the program exited with error)

Assuming I have the timeout (as duration) somehow passed into my program, I guess one approach is to

**a**) create a context with Deadline adding timeout to current time

```golang
myDeadline := time.Now().Add(timeout * time.Second)
ctx, cancel := context.WithDeadline(context.Background(), myDeadline)
defer cancel()
```

**b**) have the final function communicate its result via a channel (I think this is called the channel generator pattern?)

```golang
func fxn2() (chan string) {

 resChan := make(chan string)

   go func() {
   // get the job done
   resChan <- result
   }()
 return resChan
}
```

and

**c**) then block the main goroutine on a select statement as follows

```golang
select {
  case err := <-ctx.Done():
    log.Println("Process has timed out...exiting")
    os.Exit(err)
  case result := <- resChan
    log.Println("Process completed in time")
}
```

This is the best I can think of for now, but I was wandering whether there is a better or more go-idiomatic way (say with spanwing new copies of contexts for each function - that should of course accept `context.Context` as input arguments) that somehow track the remaining time?)

Comment: Normally you pass the context to the functions that need to act on it, but you're not doing anything here `time.After` couldn't handle. I don't know what you mean by "spanwing new copies of contexts for each function", so I'm not sure what you expect to happen (and you have deadline and timeout confused, your first example won't compile). Yes it's normal to share a context across multiple function calls, but what exactly are you asking?

Comment: yeah I fixed that typo

Comment: the `time.After` should be in the `select` statement? if so, my program will have already be running until it reaches that point, right? so the usage of the timeout will not be so accurate (but I must have misunderstood your suggestion). on the contrary (my assumption was) that the usage of `Deadline` would be more accurate because the deadline is now (when the program starts) PLUS the timeout

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use `time.After`, I'm simply stating that there's very little difference from your example of the context usage, either way you will exit immediately after the timeout. What is your end goal here?

Comment: If your goal is to simply have a deadline set from when the program starts, this will work, so what isn't working as you expected?

Comment: I want the call to `func1()` and the call to `func2()` (etc) to last either `timeout` seconds, or the program to fail; the functions are called sequentially and not concurrently in other goroutines

Comment: If by `this` you mean my example, I was just wandering whether there is a more go idiomatic way of achieving the same thing; I was under the (potentially wrong) impression that in such use cases, the functions should be somehow sharing the same context

Comment: You don't need them to share anything since you can throw away the results if they're not ready in time. Exiting the process will terminate the remaining coroutines.

Comment: See the pattern here: https://golangbyexample.com/select-statement-with-timeout-go/

Comment: Your example will not abort the job when the timeout is exceeded, it will continue running and then just ignore the result. If that's the intention you could probably simplify it even more.

Answer (score 3):

This is more complicated than it needs to be. There are two ways to do this:

1. If the functions take a `context.Context` argument, you don't need to wait for `<-ctx.Done()` at the top level. Instead, when the context finishes, the functions will (after some unknown unknown delay, possibly never, depending on the function) return `ctx.Err()` (which should be `context.DeadlineExceeded`).
2. If the functions do not take a `context.Context` argument, then you can just exit the process. You don't need a `context.Context` to do this. All I mean by that is that the `context.Context` is just a more complicated way to call `<-time.After(timeout)`.

```golang
type myResultType struct{}

func longFunctionCall() (*myResultType, error) {
    ...
}

func invokeFunctionWithDeadline() {
    const timeout = 10 * time.Second

    // Run the function on a goroutine, and return the result with a channel.
    type resultStruct struct {
        value *myResultType
        err error
    }
    ch := make(chan resultStruct)
    go func() {
        v, err := longFunctionCall()
        ch <- resultStruct{v, err}
    }()

    // Wait for either the timeout, or the result.
    select {
    case <-time.After(timeout):
        log.Println("Timed out")
        os.Exit(1)
    case result := <-ch:
        log.Println("Success:", result)
    }
}
```

Note that this strategy only works because you are calling `os.Exit()`, which forcibly terminates all outstanding goroutines.

Comment: that is a nice pattern; I assume it does not change much considering I have `longFunctionCall1`, `longFunctionCall2`, 3, 4...

Comment: Yes, you can put those inside the `go func() { ... }`